# Removing a duplicate in the legend in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got an annoying duplicate in my legend for the data and code below I'm struggling to remove:

```
ggplot(communitiesdata1, aes(`avg time to first response?`, `response rate`)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, 
             aes(fill=helpfulness, stroke=0.1,
                 colour = helpfulness,
                 size=`threads active in past 30 days`)) +  
  scale_fill_gradient2(high="red", low="blue", midpoint = mid) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=community,
                  ),
                  size = 3, # font size in the text labels
                  point.padding = 0, # additional padding around each point
                  box.padding = 0.3, # additional padding around each text label
                  ) +
  labs(title = "Community Category Performance - Jan 2021", 
       y = "Response Rate %", 
       x = "Avg. time to first response (mins)") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text=element_text(size=9), axis.title=element_text(size=9), plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust=0.5), legend.title=element_text(size=7), 
    legend.text=element_text(size=6))
```

This gives me the following outcome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY3x5.png)

Does anyone know how to remove the duplicate in the legend? I want to remove the first one (the light to dark blue gradient)

Comment: It's probably because you're mapping `helpfulness` to `colour` as well and the blue gradient is the colour legend. Remove line 4 of your code and it should disappear.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @teunbrand that actually fixed it. Damn that was simple, thanks :-)